# Search rows in a table and compare them to other rows

Tags: c#

I have created an application that parses some text files and pulls out and sorts the information into a table

Here is a sample

```
NODE    DSP Name    BUS   IDENT   STATION         REF1                  REF2

nnn1_1  S|xxxx|A1   1      1        1             S|yyyyyyyyyy|A1       S|zzzzzzz|A1

mmm1_1  R|xxxx|A1   1      1        1             R|yyyyyyyyyy|A1       R|zzzzzzz|A1

xxx1_2  R|xxxx|A1   1      1        1             R|yyyyyyyyyy|A1       R|zzzzzzz|A1

yyy1_1  R|xxxx|A1   1      1        1             R|yyyyyyyyyy|A1       R|zzzzzzz|A1
```

I need to check 3 things

1. That if in the DSP Name there is a `S|` that it has at least one corresponding R|
2. That the corresponding `R|` have identical `BUS`, `IDENT`, `STATION`
3. That `REF1` and `REF2` match names

I can sort of brute force my way through this pulling in the table one line at a time and building a list of all the (`S|`) and then once have that list search for the corresponding (`R|`)... 
I already have the these in a datatable at one point, as well as a CSV file

Is there a simpler way to do this? Like LINQ?

Comment: I don't know where your column boundaries are.  CAn you please format your question?  Also, you say it's in a table... `DataTable`?  In a database?  Waht type of database?  Or do you mean an HTML table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
var dspStartsWithR = From row in myDataTable.Rows
                     Where (string)row("DSP Name").StartsWith("R|")
var dspStartsWithS = From row in myDataTable.Rows
                     Where (string)row("DSP Name").StartsWith("S|")
```

Once you get your results you're going to have to do some combination of Substring to strip out the characters you don't need, do comparisons, etc. My C# is rusty so sorry if the code isn't quite right.

Comment: Thank you I just needed to get started with something and this looks like it will help me overcome my analysis paralysis.  I have been programming for some time but dealing large amounts of data is something new to me.  I appreciate the help

Comment: This works                                                         'var queryDspStartsWithR = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           where r.Field<string>("DSP                                   Name").StartsWith("S|")
                                     select r;'

Comment: Good. Just as a random aside: the `select r` above wouldn't be necessary, unlike SQL. You'd only need it if you wanted to do something extra, like select a specific object on a property, or format something differently.